# GPUImage3 simulator error (`Error: MPS does not support the iOS simulator.')

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, gpuimage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9tHl.png)

Using GPUImage3 framwork on iOS 13 ,

I have these errors:

```
Touch the screen of the simulator -> error. `Error: MPS does not support the iOS simulator.'
```

Can't run simulator using metal kit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Developing Metal Apps that Run in Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/developing_metal_apps_that_run_in_simulator):

> In Xcode 11, Simulator adds support for Metal development. You can
>   write iOS and tvOS apps that use Metal and test them in the Simulator,
>   gaining the benefits of hardware acceleration on the Mac during
>   development of your app.

and [Supporting Simulator in a Metal App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/supporting_simulator_in_a_metal_app)

I guess this crash related to framework GPUImage3, but..I tried to run the code from Apple. The app crashes, unfortunately.

updated: MetalPerformanceShaders is not supported on the simulator currently.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with iOS 13 the simulator now supports Metal but without Metal Performance Shaders.

If you want to run GPUImage3 on the simulator you can change this:

```swift
if #available(iOS 9, macOS 10.13, *) {
    self.metalPerformanceShadersAreSupported = MPSSupportsMTLDevice(device)
} else {
    self.metalPerformanceShadersAreSupported = false
}
```

to the following:

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    self.metalPerformanceShadersAreSupported = false
#else
    if #available(iOS 9, macOS 10.13, *) {
        self.metalPerformanceShadersAreSupported = MPSSupportsMTLDevice(device)
    } else {
        self.metalPerformanceShadersAreSupported = false
    }
#endif
```